# this.props.fb is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Iam new to redux/react . Iam a doing a simple rest call to fetch some details by triggering an action . But iam getting the following error

```
BSC.js?d219:24 Uncaught TypeError: 
this.props.fb is not a function.
```

My code is as follows 
Actions-

```
export function fb(){
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({
          type: SUCCESS,
          payload: {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"} 
         })
       }
}
```

Container -

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {fb} from '../../actions/b/bSA';

export class BSC extends React.Component {


componentDidMount(){
  this.props.fb();
}

render(){
    return <div></div>
}
}
export default connect(null, {fB})(BSC);
```

Reducer

```
  const initialState = {
  loading: true,
  error: null,
  };
export default function bSR(state = initialState, action) {

switch(action.type) {

  case SUCCESS:

    return {
      ...state,
      loading: false,

    };

    default:
    // ALWAYS have a default case in a reducer
    return state;
    }
    }
```

What could be the issue ?

Comment: Capitalization? fB

Answer (score 0):

Just spit balling, but I believe you are lacking a MapStateToProps function which would actually attach that function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare this method in your container component file.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return bindActionCreators({
        fb
    }, dispatch);
};
```

where `bindActionCreators` is:

```
import {bindActionCreators} from "redux";
```

Now pass it to connect method:

```
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(BSC);
```

What happens here is `mapDispatchToProps` function gets `dispatch` as function parameter and it has to be passed to action creator to actually dispatch the action. Here `bindActionCreators` calls your action creator method with the `dispatch` as parameter and you will be able to dispatch the required action there.

Comment: Can you tell me how you have imported BSC component in other file?